# What does @ mean in R?

Tags: r, function, sapply

I've started reading about Species Distribution Modelling in R, and am commonly coming across the symbol '@' being used, often as part of a function within 'sapply'. Can anyone tell me what it means / what it is doing? Here are some examples:

```
auc <- sapply(list(a, b, c), function(x) x@auc)

sapply( e, function(x){ x@t[which.max(x@TPR + x@TNR)] } )
```

For the second example, 'e' is an object of class 'ModelEvaluation', where "max TPR+TNR at :" is one of the outputs from the model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried `?"@"`?

Comment: In the future, please try searching StackOverflow before posting a question. Often, the question has already been asked and the answer is already provided.

Comment: @Thomas, I did try, and didn't find anything. Search engines aren't perfect so no need to get snooty!

Comment: Conducting a "regular" search with special characters can be tricky sometimes. Actually I wouldn't have found the previous question either. What did you search for, @Thomas?

Comment: I'm not being snooty; that's just how this site is supposed to work. The question is found [in search results based on a reasonable query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22%40+symbol%22). That said, I've opened [a question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290309/improve-search-results-for-at-symbol) in response to your feedback that will hopefully lead to improvements in such search results in the future.